# How do I get the SD card slot to work on my Dell Latitude 2120?

Tags: drivers, dell, realtek, sd-card

The SD card reader on my Dell Latitude 2120, running Ubuntu 14.10 does nothing when I insert an SD card into it. I unsuccessfully looked for a solution online, and apparently the drivers for the Realtek RTS5208 SD card reader that the Latitude uses aren't included by default in Ubuntu. I found a driver for the card reader ([on this page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-2120/drivers)) for Ubuntu 10.10 (Change the OS in the drop-down menu to Ubuntu 10.10, then look under "Drivers for OS Deployment" to get to the driver.) However,, when I try to install the .deb package that is inside of the downloaded .tar.gz package, it fails to install. This is the output I get from trying to install it with `sudo dpkg -i realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader-dkms_1.10.10_all.deb`:

```
(Reading database ... 254964 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader-dkms_1.10.10_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.10.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader-dkms (1.10.10) over (1.10.10) ...
Setting up realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader-dkms (1.10.10) ...
Loading new realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader-1.10.10 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-32-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.13.0-32-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rts-pstor-pcie-media-card-reader/1.10.10/build/make.log for more information.
```

How do I get the card reader to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fresh installing Ubuntu 16.04 x64, it seems like the drivers for the SD card are now included in Ubuntu, as the SD card reader is now working perfectly without any tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same model, but I have a realtek in my HP (RTS5229) and the Realtek drivers from [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=25&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTS5101/RTS5111/RTS5116/RTS5169) work perfectly.

Comment: @Tim this is not a question. OP is suggesting the use of drivers from the RealTek website.

Comment: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/searchView.aspx?keyword=RTS5208

Answer (score 0):

http://downdrivers.com/down-driver-dell-latitude-2120-notebook-realtek-rts5208-card-reader-driver-a03.html

I also have a Dell Latitude 2120. Just download the driver where it says download and pop your SD card in. Enjoy.

Comment: Which link is for the Linux version?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorial [here](https://dainaccio.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/realtek-sd-reader-mounting-problems-under-linux-mintubuntu/). From the tutorial:

> The solution to this problem is to remove __devinit keywords from rtsx.c file.
> Open the file with a text editor and modify lines 916, 1080 and 1107:
>
> ```
> static void __devexit rtsx_remove(struct pci_dev *pci) => static void  rtsx_remove(struct pci_dev *pci)
>
> static int __devinit rtsx_probe(struct pci_dev *pci, const struct pci_device_id *pci_id) => static int  rtsx_probe(struct pci_dev *pci, const struct pci_device_id *pci_id)
>
> .remove = __devexit_p(rtsx_remove), => .remove = rtsx_remove,"
> ```

It still wasn't working for me. In addition to the steps provided in the tutorial I had to comment out line 275 `.proc_info = proc_info` in the `rtsx.c` file. Now my Dell 2120s sd reader works fine.

After this `make`, `make install`, `depmod`, `reboot`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still need to compile and reboot - will reply once I'm done - but gedit tells me that the `.proc_info = proc_info` line is on line 265 rather than 275. Also, how did you find that tutorial? I spent a long time Googling different things, and couldn't find anything.